# duplicate a value for using multiple listview in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, logic

i have 3 listview in my project, getting value from backend(Firebase), the values are checked 2 times in stream builder ,but they are listed in 3 times

Comment: Brief more your question. Share some code snippets.

Comment: can you share your code and server response